# JavaScript and querySelector

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="allSteps">
  <h3>Intermediate steps</h3>
  <span class="staticStep">→ <img src="" alt="intermediate step" class="image" ></span>
  <span class="staticStep">→ <img src="" alt="intermediate step" class="image"></span>
  <span class="staticStep">→ <img src="" alt="intermediate step" class="image"></span>
</div>
```

In javaScript, how do I access the .src for each image?

I tried the following but it gives me an error:

```
document.querySelector(".staticStep img").src[0] = images[num][0];
document.querySelector(".staticStep img").src[1] = images[num][1];
document.querySelector(".staticStep img").src[2] = images[num][2];
```

I also tried the following but it gives me a an error:

```
document.querySelector(".staticStep img")[0].src = images[num][0];
document.querySelector(".staticStep img")[1].src = images[num][1];
document.querySelector(".staticStep img")[2].src = images[num][2];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) which returns *all* of the possible results instead of just the first one.  The error you're getting (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined`) is because `querySelector` only returns the first element found, not an array (and elements can't be accessed like arrays).

jQuery (the inspiration for `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`) *always* allows you to access like an array (`$('.staticStep img')[0]` works), so this is probably where your confusion stems from.

Quick JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/j8ZUJ/1/

Comment: Why does querySelector blindly choose the first matching element as it goes down the html code instead of doing breadth-first search and choosing the first matching element that is closest in depth to the parent???

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector returns the **[first element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)** within the document thus the error. you probalbly want to try: **document.querySelectorAll**

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".staticStep img");

elements[0].src  =.....
elements[1].src  =.....
elements[2].src  =.....
```

Or you could use jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to return all src:

```
map = Function.prototype.call.bind([].map);
map(document.querySelectorAll(".image"), function(o){
    return o.src;
});
```

or set src just with

```
o.src="whatever";
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3q2a2/).

Look [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for compatibility of `map`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
document.querySelector('.staticStep :nth-child(i)').src = images[num][i];

where i = 0,1,2,--- ,n.
```