# How do I check two options at once in the option quiz?

Tags: javascript, html

I did it as you wanted and it still doesn't work as it should, if I don't check anything in the checkbox and give it an "evaluate test" so it will write me 1 point anyway, which is wrong. Some ideas?

```
function check(){
    var question1 = document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked');
    var question2 = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="question2"]:checked', 'input[value="question2"]:checked');
    var correct = 0;

    if (question1 !=null && question1.value == " Červená, Zelená, Modrá") {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question4 !=null &&question4.value == "Rastrová grafika","Vektorová grafika"){
    correct++;
}

    document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "Máš " + correct + " otázky/otázek správně.";
}
```

```html
<form class="quiz">
  <p style="font-weight: 900">V RGB modelu se jedná o jaké barvy?</p>
  <input type="radio" class='question1' name="question1" value=" Červená, Zelená, Modrá"> Červená, Zelená, Modrá<br>
  <input type="radio" class='question1' name="question1" value=" Červená, Zelená, Žlutá"> Červená, Zelená, Žlutá<br>
  <input type="radio" class='question1' name="question1" value=" Černá, Fialová, Modrá"> Červená, Fialová, Modrá<br>
</form>
<form class="quiz">
  <p style="font-weight: 900">Způsoby jakým počítače ukládají a zpracovávají obrazové informace se nazývají? (Vyber dvě možnosti)</p>
  <input type="checkbox" class='question2' name="question4" value=" 3D grafika"> 3D grafika<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class='question2' name="question4" value=" Vektorová grafika"> Vektorová grafika<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class='question2' name="question4" value=" Fotografika"> Fotografika<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class='question2' name="question4" value=" Rastrová grafika"> Rastrová grafika<br>
</form>
<br>
<div id="number_correct"></div>
```

Comment: `question2` needs to be the result of a call to querySelectorAll, not just querySelector. It will then be a list of all the checked elements. You would need to loop the list and see what it contains. (querySelector only returns the first matched element (as per its documentation!), which is why it's not suitable for looking at multiple items).

Comment: where is number_correct in HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574692/javascript-and-queryselector

Comment: No, I don't see my solution there. @isherwood

Comment: @JakubMitrega isherwood's link is basically the same idea as my comment above - you need to use querySelectorAll to select _all_ the checked boxes, not just the first one. It may not be the exact same example as your situation but the concept is the same.

Comment: Well, it's not very clear what problem you're facing. "I can't add a score" isn't very specific.

Comment: P.S. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall

Comment: Please take a look at what I just posted for the update, @ADyson or someone

Comment: You've only done one of the things I listed. Look at my first comment again. Also querySelectorAll only takes one argument, you don't need the second argument (especially since it's identical to the first!). It will automatically select all matching elements of the first selector, you don't need to list the same selector multiple times. Read the documentation properly and/or update your understanding of how CSS selectors work. Also I don't know where you think `question4`'s value would come from. Double-check 1) my comment, 2) the documentation and 3) your work, carefully, then try again

Comment: Your second `if` statement's syntax is also invalid. This should be throwing console errors all over the place. There seems to be a lot of guesswork going on.

Comment: No, it doesn't throw mistakes right now @ADyson

Comment: I disagree. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/84h9jmwL/ - press the Check Answers button I created and there is a console error immediately: `Uncaught ReferenceError: question4 is not defined`. So unless you aren't even running this code at all, or your code is different to what you've posted here, then that statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`question2` needs to be the result of a call to [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), not just [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). It will then be a list of all the checked elements (querySelector only returns the first matched element, no matter how many match the selector.

You would need to loop the list and see what it contains. You need to verify that only two boxes were checked, and that they were the correct ones.

Also in your code, the `question4` variable isn't defined, and `input[value="question2"]:checked` will never match anything - there's no checkbox with that value, and looking for the value makes no sense anyway. Also your question2 checkboxes randomly had "question4" as their name. I've corrected those issues and a couple of other minor things.

Something like this will work better:

```js
function check() {
  var question1 = document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked');
  var question2 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="question2"]:checked');
  var correct = 0;

  if (question1 != null && question1.value == "Červená, Zelená, Modrá") {
    correct++;
  }

  var q2answers = ["Rastrová grafika", "Vektorová grafika"];
  var correctQ2NumAnswers = (q2answers.length == question2.length);
  var correctQ2AnswersCount = 0;

  question2.forEach(function(el) {
    if (q2answers.includes(el.value)) correctQ2AnswersCount++;;
  });
 
  if (correctQ2NumAnswers == true && correctQ2AnswersCount == q2answers.length) correct++;

  document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "Máš " + correct + " otázky/otázek správně.";
}

document.querySelector("#check").addEventListener("click", check);
```

```html
<form class="quiz">
  <p style="font-weight: 900">V RGB modelu se jedná o jaké barvy?</p>
  <input type="radio" class='question1' name="question1" value="Červená, Zelená, Modrá"> Červená, Zelená, Modrá<br>
  <input type="radio" class='question1' name="question1" value="Červená, Zelená, Žlutá"> Červená, Zelená, Žlutá<br>
  <input type="radio" class='question1' name="question1" value="Černá, Fialová, Modrá"> Červená, Fialová, Modrá<br>
</form>
<form class="quiz">
  <p style="font-weight: 900">Způsoby jakým počítače ukládají a zpracovávají obrazové informace se nazývají? (Vyber dvě možnosti)</p>
  <input type="checkbox" class='question2' name="question2" value="3D grafika"> 3D grafika<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class='question2' name="question2" value="Vektorová grafika"> Vektorová grafika<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class='question2' name="question2" value="Fotografika"> Fotografika<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class='question2' name="question2" value="Rastrová grafika"> Rastrová grafika<br>
</form>
<br>
<div id="number_correct"></div>
<button type="button" id="check">
Check Answers
</button>
```